# BoxPlot on R program with specific data

Tags: r, boxplot

Being new to R, I have some problems in mind. Can you guys help me with it?

I have a series of data

```
X     Gender     Score         Postal
1       F       427.395        123455
2       F       922.080        642362
3       M       114.500        123947 
4       M       176.345        236835
5       F       523.140        849729
```

Above is a sample of 500 data.

I wish to do a boxplot on scores for females and males separately and also. However, there's the postal code which will be captured in the boxplot as well. How do I make the conditions for boxplot to capture data from only X and Score, classified by gender?

I have tried to do sorting first before plotting boxplot, but can't seem to make it work. Do you guys have any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: C'mon, the very **first** Google result for "R boxplot" tells you the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Calling your data `df`, use:

```
boxplot(Score~Gender,data=df)
```

[image]

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=Gender, y=Score, color=Gender))
```

[image]